# Laravel Idea Does not route to the source of truth

Tags: php, laravel

I generated helper code using Laravel Idea.

The Laravel Idea works well, but is there a way to be routed to the source of truth.

Example:

Say you Generate Helper Code. When clicking on let's say SomeModel::create() it would be nice to be routed to its definition in Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php it instead routes me to the generated helper docs inside _laraverl_idea/_ide_helper_model_builders_76a5a1e06............php

Is there a way to make it route you to the real source of truth, which would be in this case Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php.

Thanks

Comment: Use Model::query()->create([]);

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I should of been more clear and mention that I did not want to have to go through the query method every time. Would be nice to just use Model::query()

Thanks you @marius-ciclistu

Comment: I faced the same issue. I fixed it using query().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in the last update - 7.1

Comment: Wow this was great timing. I’m glad ithe fix was addled. Thanks